# Python Sockets клиент получает только 1 сообщение

Tags: python, сокет, websocket

Мой Python сервер на Sockets посылает несколько сообщений, хотя клиент распознаёт и получает только одно (первое сообщение). Как сделать чтобы клиент мог получать несколько сообщений?

server.py

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("127.0.0.1", 2200))
server.listen(1)

while True:
    data = input("Enter Command: ")
    socket, address = server.accept()
    socket.sendall(data.encode("utf-8"))
```

client.py

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("127.0.0.1", 2200))

while True:
    data = client.recv(2048)
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Ну так вы на второй итерации цикла блокируете поток выполнения ожиданием нового поключения (`accept`). Попробуйте вынести `accept` из цикла.

Answer (score 0):

я делаю это вот так:

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("127.0.0.1", 2200))

while True:
    #принимаем первое сообщение
    data = client.recv(2048)
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
    # принимаем второе сообщение
    data = client.recv(2048)
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```